# The correct way to load and read JSON file contains special characters in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, unicode

I'm working with a JSON file contains some unknown-encoded strings as the example below:

```
"L\u00c3\u00aa Nguy\u00e1\u00bb\u0085n Ph\u00c3\u00ba"
```

I have loaded this text by using `json.load()` function in `Python 3.7` environment and tried to encode/decode it with some methods I found around the Internet but I still cannot get the proper string as I expected. (In this case, it has to be `Lê Nguyễn Phú`).

My question is, which is the encoding method they used and how to parse this text in a proper way in Python?

Because the JSON file comes from an external source that I didn't handle so that I cannot know or make any changes in the process of encoding the text.

**[Updated] More details:**

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
 "content":"L\u00c3\u00aa Nguy\u00e1\u00bb\u0085n Ph\u00c3\u00ba"
}
```

Firstly, I loaded the JSON file:

```
 with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

But when I extract the content, it's not what I expected:

```
string = data.get('content', '')
print(string)

'LÃª Nguyá»\x85n PhÃº'
```

Comment: The problem is that the original file is encoded incorrectly.

Comment: "L\u00c3\u00aa Nguy\u00e1\u00bb\u0085n Ph\u00c3\u00ba" contains unicode characters ... but they are not the unicode characters you are expecting ...

Comment: "and tried to encode/decode it with some methods I found around the Internet" Please show actual code of things you actually tried. Also, where did the file come from? Could we see a hex dump of the relevant portion of the file? Does "the example below" reflect how it looks in the file when you open it in a text editor, or does it reflect how it looks after you `json.load()` and display the string?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm sorry because I haven't shown you clearly what I have troubles on. So, I have just updated my post! Because it is my first question in StackOverFlow so if you see any problems with my posts or answers, please let me know. I appreciate your suggestion a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone took "Lê Nguyễn Phú", encoded that as UTF-8, and then took the resulting series of *bytes* and lied to a JSON encoder by telling it that those bytes were the characters of a string. The JSON encoder then cooperatively produced garbage by encoding those characters. But it is reversible garbage. You can reverse this process using something like

```
json.loads(in_string).encode("latin_1").decode("utf_8")
```

Which decodes the string from the JSON, extracts the bytes from it (the 256 symbols in Latin-1 are in a 1-to-1 correspondence with the first 256 Unicode codepoints), and then re-decodes those bytes as UTF-8.

The big problem with this technique is that it only works if you are sure that *all* of your input is garbled in this fashion... there's no completely reliable way to look at an input and *decide* whether it should have this broken decoding applied to it. If you try to apply it to a validly-encoded string containing codepoints above U+00FF, it will crash. But if you try to apply it to a validly-encoding string containing only codepoints up to U+00FF, it will turn your perfectly good string into a different kind of garbage.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make sure of a few things with OP, but I'm pretty sure this is the answer. Looks like we've found a case of double-UTF-(m)8. ;) I'll add that *if at all possible, the problem should be fixed at the source, or arranged to be fixed at the source*.

Comment: @hobbs Thank you a lot for helping me! Your suggestion is exactly what I'm looking for. My problem is that I do not know what method they used to encode the text (as you know it's `latin_1`). Some lines in your explanation section I need to research more to understand (due to my lack of knowledge about this topic), but your answer is enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: @nguyendhn FYI, the code line won't work as shown.  The result of `json.loads` with your example will be a dictionary, not a string.  The real fix is even uglier because each value in the dictionary has to be encoded/decoded individually. For example:  `D = json.loads(in_string); D['content'] = D['content'].encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`.

Comment: Yes. Actually this is exactly the way I fixed my problem according to your suggestion. :D Thank you a lot!